# Problem with working with python package kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Error was something like this:

> File "c:/Users/hp/OneDrive/Desktop/Python/big.py", line 26, in 
> Myapp().run()
> File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
> self._run_prepare()
> File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 925, in _run_prepare
> raise Exception('Invalid instance in App.root')

And my code was this:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core import text
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class layout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Username= "))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        cell_1 = self.username
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Password= "))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False)
        cell_2 = self.password



class Myapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return layout

if __name__== "__main__":
    Myapp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first change I made was capitalizing your class 'layout' to 'Layout'.
This is a PEP8 convention in python and helps avoid confusion.

The problem with your code is in the MyApp().build() method... You tried to return a class you never instantiated.

When you create a class template using the 'class' keyword. It's just a template. In order to create the actual object from the template, you have to call the class name with a set of parentheses ( ).

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core import text
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


# Class names should always be CamelCase style
# Changed the name of layout to Layout
class Layout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        # Changed layout to Layout here too
        super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Username= "))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        cell_1 = self.username
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Password= "))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False)
        cell_2 = self.password



class Myapp(App):
    def build(self):

        # Changes made here
        # You never created an instance of your 'layout()' class
        # To create an instance you have to use ( and )
        layout = Layout()

        return layout

if __name__== "__main__":
    Myapp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you must call layout class

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class Layout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Username= "))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Password= "))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```